# Deep nested components not displaying

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm having trouble displaying the third nested component.

Expected:

> Hello App Component
>
> Hello Nest-A Component
>
> Hello Nest-1 Component
>
> Hello Test-Z Component

Actual:

> Hello App Component
>
> Hello Nest-A Component
>
> Hello Nest-1 Component

Why is my Test-Z component not displaying?

TLDR; [StackBlitz - Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaugjn)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NestAModule } from './nest-a/nest-a.module';

const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'nest-a', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'nest-a', redirectTo: 'nest-a', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRoutes),
    NestAModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent, 
  ],
  bootstrap: [ 
    AppComponent 
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello App Component</h1><router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**nest-a/nest-a-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NestAComponent } from './nest-a.component';
import { Nest1Component } from './nest-1/nest-1.component';

export const nestARoutes = [
  {
    title: 'Nest A',
    path: 'nest-a',
    component: NestAComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'nest-1', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'nest-1', component: Nest1Component },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(nestARoutes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class NestARoutingModule { }
```

**nest-a/nest-a.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-nest-a',
    template: `<h1>Hello Nest-A Component</h1><router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class NestAComponent {
}
```

**nest-a/nest-a.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NestAComponent } from './nest-a.component';
import { NestARoutingModule, nestARoutes } from './nest-a-routing.module';
import { Nest1Module } from './nest-1/nest-1.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NestAComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    NestARoutingModule,
    Nest1Module,
    RouterModule.forChild(nestARoutes),
  ],
})
export class NestAModule { }
```

**nest-a/nest-1/nest-1-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Nest1Component } from './nest-1.component';
import { TestYComponent } from './test-y/test-y.component'
import { TestZComponent } from './test-z/test-z.component'

export const nest1Routes = [
  {
    title: 'Nest 1',
    path: 'nest-1',
    component: Nest1Component,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'test-z', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'test-y', component: TestYComponent},
      { path: 'test-z', component: TestZComponent},
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(nest1Routes),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class Nest1RoutingModule { }
```

**nest-a/nest-1/nest-1.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-nest-1',
    template: `<h1>Hello Nest-1 Component</h1><router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

export class Nest1Component {
}
```

**nest-a/nest-1/nest-1.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Nest1Component } from './nest-1.component';
import { Nest1RoutingModule, nest1Routes } from './nest-1-routing.module';
import { TestZModule } from './test-z/test-z.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Nest1Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    Nest1RoutingModule,
    TestZModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(nest1Routes),
  ],
})
export class Nest1Module { }
```

**nest-a/nest-1/nest-*/nest-*.component.ts**

(there is an Y and Z, the are no important differences)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-test-*',
    template: `<h1>Hello Test-* Component</h1>`
})

export class Test*Component {
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that

Comment: seems related to routes, I didn't figured it out yet, btw even if you put the whole path as `/nest-a/nest-1/test-z` doesn't find the route

Comment: You can pass `{ enableTracing: true }` as a second parameter to the `.forRoot()` method to help you debug the problem. the router will print some useful info in the console.

Comment: @LucaRegazzi  Thanks, I didn't know that existed.  However it is more like a trace than a debug.  It only logs useful information if the route was found, otherwise nothing is really logged.  :(

Comment: i think i have some idea where the problem lies, but i'm not able to solve it keeping all the redirects.. The angular router wants to fully consume the url while matching it against the rules. The problem is that the empty path matches all 3 redirect conditions (the one to redirect to nest-a the one to nest-1 and the one to test-z). all these redirects might confuse the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my code Luca Regazzi's Answer I started getting the following error messsage in production.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
>
> Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

It appears that with AOT there is even another way to loadChildren Documented [In this Bug Report on Angular/Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14763).

Instead of:

```
import { MyComponent } from './path/mycomponent.component';

...

loadChildren: () => MyComponent
```

it should be:

```
// no import

...

loadChildren: () => import('./path/mycomponent.component')
  .then(m => m.MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are wrong in your code and cause some trouble to the router resolution:

- Your paths are divided in different modules but in the routes definition you are telling the router to load direcly a component and not the entire sub-module (which contains the sub-module routes definitions)
- In your sub-module you need to have the first path as empty to load the module main component (in nest-1 module your empty path would load the nest-1 component. it's not the parent module that has the job to load the sub-module *entry* component)
- Your routes are set-up both in the router-module and in the main module (ex: both in the nest-a.module and nest-a.routing.module you have this line `RouterModule.forChild(nestARoutes),`). They must be defined only in one place (the routing module, and then import it the main module)
- The router is responsible of loading the sub-module (using the `loadChildren` property in the path definition) so you don't need to import the sub-module in your parent module (es: nest-a.module doesn't need to import nest-1.module

Below you find your example modified as explained above. The main 2 things are:

- In your parent module route definition you need to use the `loadChildren` property to load the sub-module (and his route definition)
- In the sub-module you have the first path as empty and load the sub-module *entry* component (es: nest-1 module will load the nest-1 component)

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpidzy)

Hope i was clear enough.

Comment: SO many articles don't talk about `loadChildren` ... I'm migrating a ton of my code, we'll see how it goes :)  Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow it looks so much better.  Thank you.